# ng-cordova createFile () method (In file API) is not working in android devices

Tags: file, cordova, ionic-framework, device

I am trying to create a simple text file in my android device (cordova 6.0.0 and Ionic 1.7.14) but every time its prints the error object hence file is not created. I tested this with Samsung/ Huawei and HTC devices but the result is same. app.js and index.js is as follows and request any help.

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaFile) {

//----------------------------create file---------------------
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

   $cordovaFile.createFile("cordova.file.dataDirectory", "xcendant.txt", false)
      .then(function (success) {
        // success
       alert(success);
        alert("success!");
       // console.log("Elaa");
      }, function (error) {
        // error
        alert(error);
        alert("fail");
      });
    })

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
   <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MyCtrl">



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the error that you're getting from the console. Also, verify that you have the correct File Permissions for Android. You might need to allow file permissions in your config.xml. `<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />`

Comment: Hi @johnborges,  Thanx for your clue. This is the error, triggered by the error function. "TypeError" and I have given the permission in config.xml as u suggested but still the result is same.

Comment: Can you show the full error line? Anything else after TypeError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ajantha, I m not familiar with ionic framework. But if you are using Cordova file plugin with Android 6.0, there is a permission issue in plugin itself which results in failure of folder creation.This issue is still open in Apache issue tracker and in progress.will send the link on the same shortly.

**Update:** The issue is fixed in Cordova file plugin version 4.2.0. The Apache issue tracker reference link is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10798

Comment: Thanx for your info @Gandhi, I have checked this with the previous Cordova version too (5.4.0) yet the result is same and kindly request for the link.

Comment: @ajantha,i mentioned that i was facing issue while testing it on Android 6.0 and not about cordova version. The link is as follows, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10798 The issues seems to be fixed now. I need to test the same. But i m not sure what error are you exactly getting. I got PATH_EXISTS_ERR

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. In app.js code I am printing the error object using : "  alert(error); " and I have tested " alert(error.message);   "  in order to get that error message but it doesn't work. (message says undefined). Could u please make a suggestion...

Comment: @Ajantha1311, after looking at your code i understand that you are trying to write file in application data directory which i guess will not work in android unless the device is rooted. Please check this post for more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526078/cordova-file-plugin-has-wrong-directory/36038953#36038953

Comment: thanx for reply. Despite I used only one file location in the attached code, I have checked this code with all the possibilities given in ng-cordova file API. (Please refer this-http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/). Yet non of them is working.