# Can`t open local file with cordova fileopener plugin

Tags: android, cordova

on `android 5.0` device i have the issue that downloaded files can`t be opened by`cordova fileopener plugin`nor`InAppBrowser`nor`window.open`.

The file is downloaded and saved into the root path of the app given by `FileSystem.root.getURL()` -> `file:///data/data/myappid/files/files/`

If i use the cordova fileopener plugin to open the file e.g.:

```
`cordova.plugins.FileOpener.openFile("file:///data/data/myappid/files/files/mydocument.pdf", successFn, failureFn);`
```

it seems everything works. No errors and the excepted "app selection prompt" to choose e.g pdf-viewer or image viewer regading the download file mime-type are displayed. Ok so far.

But after choosing, no matter which app, an error shows up that the file couldn't be opened.

On iOS the download file can be opened with `window.open` without any problems.

I think the file isn't saved correctly on the android device, but why? Maybe the root path is not correct or any restrictions i don`t know yet.

Comment: Have tried this long back and in recent times as well. This is still a mystery to me. As far as i know, atleast i m not able to write file into application data directory. Hence you will not able to open it as it will be non existent. Check out link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526078/cordova-file-plugin-has-wrong-directory/36038953#36038953

Comment: Check out this link for working sample of fileopener - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: Ok, thx. I will check this out.

Comment: The link and sources behind helped me much. And yes, "window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.cacheDirectory" isn't working, so i changed it to "cordova.file.externalRootDirectory". I still need some improvments regarding iOS but overall question is answered. Thanks!

Comment: I m glad that it helped you as it was my first repo on github. More than happy that it helped you. Posted the answer. Please accept the same so that others get benefited. Happy coding. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have tried this long back and in recent times as well. This is still a mystery to me. As far as i know, at least i m not able to write file into application data directory. Hence you will not able to open the file as it will be non existent.

Request you to use `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` instead. For more info on fileopener plugin, check out this [Cordova file operations link](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations)

Comment: That works. Thank you. the docs didn't mention that. So you saved my time ;)